# How can I remove these textboxes after a successful login in a win32 c++ application?

Tags: c++, c

I got a small window with textbox for username and pass, locked textbox for display output and button to log in. The logging in process works good.

After a successful login, I need the window to change in that the two text boxes for username and password disappear, become locked, or deleted for the time being, whichever is simpler. I also need to change the text on the button to "logout" instead of login after a successful login. I can already change what the button does by checking the loggedin bool before choosing an action from the button, but I dont know how to change the text on it. or replace it with a different button say. I searched stuff like toggle visibility, remove textbox/window. I can't seem to find anything. If i could just remove them and trigger another WM_CREATE instance i could have a 2nd layout in that case for after logged in, But ya i don't know how to remove and maybe that's not the normal way of doing it. Answer my question or suggest a different way of doing this would be ok too. Thank you

my code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#define IDC_MAIN_BUTTON 101         // Button identifier
#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT   102         // Edit box identifier
HWND hEdit, hEdit2, noEdit;
bool loggedin = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra=NULL;
    wClass.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra=NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon=NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm=NULL;
    wClass.hInstance=hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName="Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window class creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Class Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    HWND hWnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "Window Class",
            "Windows application",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            200,
            200,
            300,
            200,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            NULL);

    if(!hWnd)
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Creation Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd,nShowCmd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));
    connect();
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Create an edit box
            hEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50,
                70,
                200,
                25,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);
            hEdit2=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50,
                95,
                200,
                25,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);

                noEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_READONLY|
                ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50,
                20,
                200,
                50,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);

            HGDIOBJ hfDefault=GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);

            SendMessage(hEdit,
                WM_SETFONT,
                (WPARAM)hfDefault,
                MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));

            SendMessage(hEdit2,
                WM_SETFONT,
                (WPARAM)hfDefault,
                MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));

            SendMessage(noEdit,
                WM_SETFONT,
                (WPARAM)hfDefault,
                MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));


            SendMessage(hEdit,
                WM_SETTEXT,
                NULL,
                (LPARAM)"Nolan");

            SendMessage(hEdit2,
                WM_SETTEXT,
                NULL,
                (LPARAM)"password");

            // Create a push button

                HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                "BUTTON",
                "Login",
                WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|
                WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                50,
                120,
                100,
                24,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);

                SendMessage(hWndButton,
                WM_SETFONT,
                (WPARAM)hfDefault,
                MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));


        }
        break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
                {

                    char buffer[256];
                    SendMessage(hEdit,
                        WM_GETTEXT,
                        sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
                    string user(buffer);
                    SendMessage(hEdit2,
                        WM_GETTEXT,
                        sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
                    string pass(buffer);

                    if(login(user, pass))   
                    {
                        loggedin = true;
                        MessageBox(NULL, "You logged in!", "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        loggedin = false;
                        MessageBox(NULL, "incorrect username or password", "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ShowWindow() to hide controls when they are not needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It seems like you're learning this but I'd definitely suggest using a more OOP approach because this can become quite a mess if you have to handle the code to each button and control in a message loop.

Comment: i was able to do everything i needed with this function.